# IE 6 javascript object type 'control'?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, fckeditor

I have a custom image selector for FCKeditor 2.6.5. Everything works fine on Firefox, Chrome and Safari. But in the IE6 I get a strange type for the selection. The code for this is:

```
alert(editorInstance.Selection.GetType());
```

And it returns 'Control'.

What is this type and how could I access the HTML of the selection instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the selection is a [ControlRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537447%28VS.85%29.aspx) as opposed to a TextRange. A ControlRange is pretty much a collection of elements that you can call commands on via its `execCommand()` method and select via its `select()` method. You get a ControlRange from the selection object in IE when you're in an editable document or element and one or more elements such as images are selected.